# Try to solve date in CLOB in DATABASE to String in Java 8 with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, clob

I have a little problem of size, to get a data formatted in `CLOB` in my DATABASE, but in string in Java  8.

In my entity class I declared

```java
@Lob
@Column(name = "EDR_DESCRIPTION")
private String edrDescription;
```

Field `EDR_DESCRIPTION` can have more of 4000 characters.

I'm taking back the data in my `serviceimpl` class with:

```java
    List<Object[]> resultList=query.getResultList();
```

And I get the data

[image: goodResult]

But with more character it doesn't work

[image: doesntWork]

And so in output

[image: output]

In my POM I declared that dependencies

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work more of 4193 characters.

Can you help me?

Comment: Which database are you connecting ti? (Oracle, maria, etc)

Comment: Database is on Oracle